# error parsing in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to this and would like some help in solving following error in below code

```
var vm = function(){
        var self = this;
        self.query = ko.observable('');
        self.locations = ko.computed(function(){
            var search = self.query().toLowerCase();
                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(locations, function(location){
                    return location.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
                });
        });
    }

        ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Message: ReferenceError: query is not defined;
Attribute value: value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'

this is the html for the above

```
<header>
    <form action="#">
        <input placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off">
    </form>
</header>
<div class="content">
    <ul data-bind="template: {name:'location', foreach:locations}">
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="location">
    <li>
        <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong> –
        <span data-bind="text: lat"></span> –
        <span data-bind="text: lng"></span>
    </li>
</script>
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: `vm` is you constructor to your model. You're passing in your constructor to the `ko.applyBindings()` function. You need to pass an instance of it. Use `new`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply will give it a try

Comment: Alternatively, you don't really need a constructor, and can just start your vm function with `var self = {};` and do `ko.applyBindings(vm())`